# RegExp sub-pattern reuse for different open-close conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Is it possible to reuse a matching `RegExp` sub-pattern for a variety of opening and closing conditions of the containing pattern?

I have a complex/long `RegExp` sub-pattern for a certain expression X, which I expect to reside within any of the open-close statements, defined as: `${...}`, `$(...)`, `$[...]`, `$/.../`, etc., which in combination makes the whole pattern (mixing open-close conditions is not accepted, or it would have been trivial).

What I want is to avoid repeating the same long X sub-pattern for each of the open-close conditions (using `|`) when defining the whole pattern, as it becomes too long and unreadable, even though it is mostly just repeated X sub-pattern.

My question - is this achievable within the `RegExp` syntax? And if yes, then how?

Environments: Node 0.12 for ES5 and IO.js 2.0 for ES6.

P.S. Strictly speaking, we are talking `RegExp` optimization here, for better code readability, and, possibly, performance.

Comment: Can you be sure that if the expression starts with one type of bracket, then it will also end with that type of bracket? Assuming that your long sub-pattern is represented by `abc`, would an expression like `/^\$[{([\/](abc)[\/\])}]/` work for you?

Comment: @JamesNewton, I'm afraid your pattern would break the strict open-close condition. I cannot use one opening pattern and a different closing one at the same time, unfortunately. Otherwise, it would have been trivial, and not much point in the entire question.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Can you use conditionals?

Comment: @JamesNewton, ES5 + ES6, running NodeJS 0.12 and IO.JS 2.0. What conditionals do you mean?

Comment: Conditionals like this: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#delimiters Example here: https://regex101.com/r/uE2wV0/1

Comment: @JamesNewton, wow, that looks about right, thank you!!! I can't work it out just yet how exactly it will work for me to be sure, too wrecked right now, 1:35am here, will pick it up tomorrow and get back here. Thank you a lot for the link!!!

Comment: Ouch: I've just realized that this is for JavaScript, so it won't work. Sorry for the false hope.

Comment: Yeah, that's an ouch, aright :) Are those not even part of ES6? Well, if you can think of anything else, please let us know. I'm off for today. Cheers!

Comment: @JamesNewton You could always use [`node-pcre`](https://github.com/mscdex/node-pcre)

Comment: @vihan1086, according to NPM statistics, nobody really uses [node-pcre](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcre) any more. Probably for a reason. Anyway, it would be a bit far off a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an extremely hacky way of matching specific opening and closing braces when used together:

```
\$(?:(\[)|(\()|({)|(\/)).*?(?:(?=\2)(?=\3)(?=\4)\]|(?=\1)(?=\3)(?=\4)\)|(?=\1)(?=\2)(?=\4)}|(?=\1)(?=\2)(?=\3)\/)
                        ^^^ Inner Match Here
```

It basically looks for all groups except one specific one to be empty and happens to only work in JavaScript regex. The `.*?` section pointed out in the above code just needs to be replaced with the regex to be matched inside of the braces to match an arbitrary pattern.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aX7rH1/1

```
// Matches
${...}
$(...)
$[...]
$/.../
// Does Not Match
${...)
${...]
${.../
$(...}
$(...]
$(.../
$[...}
$[...)
$[.../
$/...}
$/...)
$/...]
```

Comment: But where would I place my sub-pattern in it?

Comment: Wow, I was almost certain that the right answer was - it cannot be done in JavaScript, but your example does work :) Thank you! I would only advise to emphasize that it is exactly the `.*?` part that's to be replaced with the sub-pattern, for it may be not very clear at first sight.

Comment: I don't know who or why down-voted such a valuable answer, but you should know it's been to put to a good use within a public project: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/lib/formatting.js#L69, the very reason I asked about it in the first place, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thank you. Some people just get angry and decide to try making themselves feel better by seeking "revenge" when their answers are downvoted. The same happened with my two top answers. No worries. They usually have around 150-250 reputation, so they lose a greater percentage than I do :).